# unexpected operator при запуске командного файла в интерпретаторе Unix

Tags: unix, shell

Только начал изучать создание командных процедур в Unix.
Пытаюсь написать простой командный файл, содержащий цикл.
Вот мой код (Он должен выводить на стандартный вывод слово Unix заданное при запуске число раз.)

```
n=$1
while test $n -gt 0
do
echo Unix
n=`expr $n - 1`
done
```

Создаю командный файл:

```
chmod +x unix_print
```

Вызываю:

```
/usr/home/files/unix_print
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
 test: -gt: unexpected operator
```

Притом если я запускаю эти команды не из командного файла, то всё работает, как предполагается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

Вводя `n=$1` ты указываешь, чтобы переменной `n` присвоилось значение первого позиционного параметра, но при вызове (`/usr/home/files/unix_print`) ты не передаёшь этого параметра и соответственно в вызове утилиты `test` он просто пропускается. и он превращается в `test -gt 0`, что с её точки зрения является не корректным, о чём она и сообщает.

Правильный вызов выглядел бы, например, так (внимание на аргумент `3`):

```
/usr/home/files/unix_print 3
```

#### Прочая критика

- В отрывке приведённого кода отсутствует she-bang (`#!/bin/sh`), понимаю, что это, по всей видимости, упрощение для поста, но всё же это вызывает некоторое недоверие...
- Вместо `expr` обычно используют встроенный в POSIX-совместимую оболочку оператор вычисления арифметического выражения (`$(( ))`).
- Как ты уже заметил, хорошей практикой является брать в кавычки *всё*, для чего не доказана необходимость обратного.

Comment: Все эти танцы с дополнительной переменной в данном примере не нужны: *for dummy in $(seq ${1:-1}); do echo Unix; done*. Как-то так.

Comment: О, нашёл правильный вариант вызова *seq*: *seq 1 1 ${1:-0}*.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было просто заключить $n в двойные кавычки:

```
n=$1
while test "$n" -gt 0
do
echo Hello World!
n=`expr "$n" - 1`
done
```